# Glue and EC2: Closing network interfaces not in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-glue, network-interface

I have a glue job with a connection to get data from SAS. Everytime it runs, it opens a network interface, and when the job got finished, the network interface continues there. It congests my subnet.

How can I delete these networks interfaces after the job got finished? I have no idea how to do that, even when I search on google I find nothing. May you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that you have the correct policies for the IAM role that's assigned to the Glue job. Specifically, the [ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteNetworkInterface.html) action will need to be added to the permission set. Then, Glue should be able to clean these up after use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).